I can't directly apply itemprop="telephone" to the <a> tag?
I'm a bit puzzled by a behavior I'm observing when trying to add microdata to my page. Specifically, I have a link in my page that includes a phone number, which seems like a standard practice. I wanted to add itemprop="telephone" to this link. However, when I validate it using the validator at schema.org, it doesn't seem to recognize the phone number.
using the following code:
<a itemprop="telephone" href="tel:000 00 00 00" title="... 000 00 00 00">000 00 00 00</a>

But if I wrap the link with a <p> tag and add itemprop="telephone" to the <p> tag like this:
<p itemprop="telephone">
    <a href="tel:000 00 00 00" title="... 000 00 00 00">
        000 00 00 00
    </a>
</p>

…it works as expected.
Can anyone shed some light on why I can't directly apply itemprop="telephone" to the  tag? Thanks in advance!

The validator you link returns "No items detected" for both snippets. If there's more context needed for code, would you mind adding it to the question?

According to the docs, every HTML element can have an itemprop attribute specified.

Schema.org’s telephone property expects a text value, not a URL value.
If you provide Microdata’s itemprop attribute on an a element, it uses the href content as value (i.e., a URL). If you provide the itemprop attribute on a p element, it uses the element content as value (i.e., text).
To provide a text value, you could also use the meaningless span element:
<a href="tel:000-00-00-00">
  <span itemprop="telephone">000 00 00 00</span>
</a>

(Note that tel URIs must not contain spaces.)
